detecting mouse events behind a transparent iframe
I'm building a Chrome Extension that when active, appends an iframe to the body of the page and is set as position  fixed to take up the whole window dimensions (0, 0 100vw, 100vh).
The iframe is transparent it self but has some absolute controls that take up little space and leave most of the body of the website visible and some of them are also draggable so we can move them to reveal the parts of the website they cover.
I need the website itself to keep being interactive, i mean, respond to clicks, mousevers, etc, i all the areas in which the iftame is transparent.
Any kind of valid suggestion is welcome.

Their is not a simple way to do this, your best option is to search for every clickable thing on the page behind the iframe, use getBoundingClientRect() to get the area it covers and create an array of all the positions on the page.
You can then get the area clicked on in the iframe and use the array to then find and click the item behind.
